# My created App cant record its internal audio

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, playback

I createad a simple app  and I use mediaplayer to play sounds but when I use screen recorder to record my app it cannot record its internal audio why is this happening, and how to fix this?

I mean why screen recorder cant record internal audio and how to fix?

Comment: `and how to fix this?` without providing code, that's asking a bit much, unfortunately, we can't guess what your code looks like or even what language you've used, it's always important to add detail to your question to the point that others can recreate the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I mean why screen recorder cant record internal audio?